# LinkedIn Videos Beta endpoints giving 500 errors

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am in the LinkedIn Videos Beta and am trying to upload a video via the API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api-beta?tabs=http#upload-the-video

As the file is over 4mb I'm splitting it out as per the requirements, and as far as I can tell all parts of my video successfully upload. I'm also recording the etag from each of these parts so that I can finalize the upload.

The endpoint `videos?action=finalizeUpload` will return a 504 with the message Gateway Timeout. The client I'm using internally uses Guzzle, and I've attempted to increase the timeout but I'm confident that isn't the issue. The reason for that is that if I load the video with the `urlencoded` video URN I will receive a 500 status with the message Internal Server Error.

```
$userUrn = 'urn:li:person:[urn]';
// register the upload, returns the upload urls
$registerResult = $client->post(
    'videos?action=initializeUpload',
    [
        "initializeUploadRequest" => [
            'owner' => $userUrn,
            "purpose" => 'FEED_VIDEO',
            "fileSizeBytes" => filesize($videoFile),
            "uploadCaptions" => false,
            "uploadThumbnail" => false
        ]
    ]
);
$videoUrn = $registerResult['value']['video'];
$uploadToken = $registerResult['value']['uploadToken'];
// split the video file into parts
exec('split -b 4194303 "' . $videoFile . '"');
$file = 'xaa';
$etags = [];
foreach($registerResult['value']['uploadInstructions'] as $i => $uploadInstructions) 
{
    $filePath = __DIR__ . '/' . $file;
    // upload the part
    $shellCmd = 'curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --upload-file "' . $filePath . '" "' . $uploadInstructions['uploadUrl'] . '" 2>&1';
    exec($shellCmd, $o);
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('/(etag:)(\s?)(.*)(\n)/', implode("\n", $o), $matches);
    $etags[] = $matches[3]
    $file++;
}
// in this prototype just remove all of these files
exec("rm xa*");

$videoStatus = $client->post(
    "videos?action=finalizeUpload",
    [
        "finalizeUploadRequest" => [
            "video" => $videoUrn,
            "uploadToken" => $uploadToken,
            "uploadedPartIds" => $etags
        ]
    ]
);
```

I have also manually verified that using split and cat on my video does produce an exact copy of the original. (I cannot say for certain what LinkedIn is doing on its side though)

The first request `initializeUpload` will return data that contains the video urn, upload token (which is usually empty, but I've been grabbing it anyway), and the upload instructions. So I know the client works. Also the curl command that uploads the video parts, also appears to work. It returns the etag, which I place into an array to send back.

As the title indicates this feature is currently a Beta, but I wasn't told to deliver feedback on the beta anywhere specific, and the API help does indicate to post a question.

Answer (score -1):

I see LinkedIn document is referring to wrong(EI) URL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api-beta?tabs=http#sample-request-5) .
You should be using

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videos?action=finalizeUpload
```

instead of

```
https://api.linkedin-ei.com/v2/videos?action=finalizeUpload
```

Comment: This is a typo on their end, I received confirmation of that from their support desk.